# CSS - Mozilla absolute position full width issue

Tags: html, css, mozilla

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TH6ej/) -

We've got some divs displayed as `table/table cell`.

Single Cell is `50% wide`, We've got `absolute` positioned element inside first cell-div. This element is `100% wide`, but its `parent` is `50% wide`.

On Chrome absolute positioned element is 100% wide of its **parent**, and on Mozilla Firefox its 100% of **screen**. Have you idea why is that?

My **goal** is to make it **100% wide of this parent**, and also note that I need it to be absolute positioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

redTry giving `width:inherit` for `#main`.

```
#main {
  width: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background: pink;
}
//below is the hack for chrome.
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
{
    .d-td div#main 
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because Mozilla doesn't support `position: relative` for any `display: table-cell` elements. Remove `position: relative` from table-cell element and create a `<div>` with `position: relative` inside it. All `position: absolute` elements inside this div will be positioned properly.